# Garbage characters being store in the array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy data from an array of character that send from main to another one in my local function and I always see garbage characters even though I've add `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Here is my partial of the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(main) ; i++){
    if (main[i] != ';'){
        local[i] = main[i];  // Copy the characters until `;` isn't found
    } else {
        local[i] = '\0' ;   // If `;` found, null terminate the copied destination.
        break;
    }
}
```

so basically the data that being send from main for example like this

`look;can;you;see;me`

```
My Local-----> 'look??y??>c?Lw?T?w??>c?2+a?'
Actual data in main---> 'look'
```

As you can see from the above example I'm trying to get only the first word and I always get garbage I don't know why?

**EDIT**:

This is the almost the whole function which 100% sure that is causing me the problem.

```
void myFunction(char main[ ]){


   for (int i = 0; i < strlen(main) ; i++){
    if (main[i] != ';'){
        local[i] = main[i];  // Copy the characters until `;` isn't found
    } else {
        local[i] = '\0' ;   // If `;` found, null terminate the copied destination.
        break;
    }
}


        if(main[i] != '\0'){


            int col = 0, row = 0;

            do {
                if(main[i] == ';' || main[i] == '\0') {
                    sending[row++][col] = '\0';
                    col = 0;
                } else {
                    sending[row][col++] = main[i];
                }
            } while(main[i++] != '\0');

        }



    }
```

Comment: Could you add the code you use to print `MyLocal`?

Comment: @Mat this is from the main function which I have no access to it, I forgot to mention that this is a homework. I will add that tag sorry.

Comment: The code you posted looks ok (if potentially inefficient). So we need to see more.

Comment: I'm going to post my whole function which I'm pretty sure is causing me the problem because I tested with my brother's code on the above part and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your code doesn't properly null-terminate `local[]` if a semicolon isn't found.

Comment: @Blastfurnace can you point me which one you are talking about? I tried to look and did check and really nothing work for me.

Comment: If there is no semicolon your code only copies `strlen(main)` characters which doesn't include the trailing null.

Comment: Is there a reason to reimplement `strncpy` and `strchr`?

Comment: @MaxLybbert what do you mean by that? You mean to use them in my code?

Comment: I've added an actual answer to expound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to take care of zero terminating the string if the ; is *not* found.  A simple fix is tweaking your for loop so it also sees the \0 in main:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(main); i++) {
```

Comment: wow that fixed my problem on my first part. now I'm having a problem on the second part of the code haha gotta look myself to find out what is wrong again.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library handles this for you.  Using `strchr` and `strncpy`:

```
size_t length = std::strlen(main);
const char* current_pos = main;
for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
    size_t chars_remaining = length - std::distance(main, current_pos);
    const char* end_of_field = std::strchr(current_pos, ';');
    if (end_of_field == NULL) {
        std::strncpy(local[i], current_pos, chars_remaining + 1);
        // we're at the end of the input
        break;
    }
    else {
        size_t field_length = std::distance(current_pos, end_of_field);
        std::strncpy(local[i], current_pos, field_length);

        // don't forget to NUL-terminate the string
        local[i][field_length] = '\0';

        // go to next character for the next iteration through loop
        current_pos = end_of_field + 1;
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer `std::find` and `std::copy` (from `<algorithm>`):

```
size_t length = std::strlen(main);
const char* current_pos = main;
for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
    size_t chars_remaining = length - std::distance(main, current_pos);
    const char* end_of_field = std::find(current_pos, current_pos + chars_remaining, ';');
    char* output_end = std::copy(current_pos, end_of_field, local[i]);

    // don't forget to NUL-terminate the string
    *output_end = '\0';

    // if we're at the end of main, then we're done;
    // we're at the end if we're on a NUL character
    if (*end_of_field == '\0')
        break;

    // go to next character for the next iteration through loop
    current_pos = end_of_field + 1;
}
```

Not the prettiest code I've ever written, but that's largely due to using C-style strings and pointer arithmetic, which don't look avoidable given the original question.  Additionally, I haven't put in the needed checks for overflow.  It's easy enough to do that, but it's even easier to use `std::vector<std::string>` and have the standard library worry about that for you.